# Counts line in a text file VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-files, counting

I am looking for a way to count the number of lines in a text file, excluding the CRLF which will be the very last line per say.

Any chance there is a simple code example for this?

Comment: Yep, it seems that there are a lot of chances for that: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=597281

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (though I found it searching the very title of your question in Google):

```
IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\test.txt").Length
```

If you are worried about empty lines at the end, then loop from all lines until you find one with contents, and delete all of them until the end. This is easy, since:

```
IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\test.txt")
```

Returns a vector of Strings.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
TextBox1.Text = ""

With OpenFileDialog1
.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
If .ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
End With

Dim intLines As Integer = 0
Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
TextBox1.Text += sr.ReadLine() & ControlChars.CrLf
intLines += 1
Loop
sr.Close()
MessageBox.Show(intLines, Me.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to calibrate the md5#sum and then check to see if the HTML is linked to the CSS and make sure you have turned on javascript

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it more useful for other readers.